# Is there a way to run a particular custom yup validation on a conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I'm using formik for our form implementation. I am currently trying to validate the ***group field*** only for the **required** property while filling and the custom validation function **validateGroup** should run only when I click on a button (conditional rendering) until then only that particular validation should not run, Please suggest a solution for this to make it work as per my requirement.

**Reason for my requirement**

That particular custom validation **validateGroup** will run a function that will make API calls, so I want that to be validated only when I click on a button, otherwise, it keeps calling the function on every key press in my form fields.

**Schema:**

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
      tasks: Yup.array().of(
        Yup.object().shape({
          title: Yup.string().required("Required"),
          description: Yup.string().required("Required"),
          group: Yup.string()
            .required("Required")
            .when(["title", "description"], {
              is: (title, description) => {
                return Boolean(title) && Boolean(description);
              },
              then: Yup.string().validateGroup("Input valid group")
            })
        })
      )
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable validation only on submitting the form pass to your Formik the props

```
validateOnChange={false} 
validateOnBlur={false}
```